# Insert a DATETIME value with only MONTH and YEAR

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm writing a stored procedure in SQL Server and I need to insert a value into `DATETIME` column with input of `MONTH` and `YEAR`.

Example: Input MONTH = 7, YEAR = 2023, the result is:

| DATETIME |
| --- |
| 2023-07-01 00:00:00.000 |

The DAY value is 01 when insert new record.

Comment: What have you tried? `datefromparts` seems like it might be what you are looking for?

Comment: `DATEFROMPARTS(@Year, @Month, 1)`

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer. Use function `DATEFROMPARTS(@Year, @Month, 1)`